# Consulta con spinner no carga los datos

Tags: android-studio

Muy buenas comunidad, esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien, tengo una consulta con un spinner que quiero cargar los datos de iuna tabla ene specifica según el siguiente arreglo en json a través de php:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="GET"){
$Patente = $_GET ['Patente_Vehiculo'] ?? NULL;
if ($Patente) {
    require("conexion1.php");
    $conexion = retornarConexion();
    if ($conexion) {
        $query="SELECT ID,N_Filas,Cant_Repuestos,Repuestos,Valor_Repuestos,Patente_Vehiculo,Activo FROM presupuesto2 WHERE 
        Patente_Vehiculo = ? and Activo = 1 Order By ID asc";
        if ($stmt=$conexion->prepare($query)) {
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $Patente);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($ID, $Filas, $Cant, $Rep, $Valor, $PatenteV, $Activo);
            $rows=array();
            while($row=$stmt->fetch()){
                $rows[]=array('ID'=>$ID,'N_Filas'=>$Filas,'Cant_Repuestos'=>$Cant,'Repuestos'=>$Rep,'Valor_Repuestos'=>$Valor,
                'Patente_Vehiculo'=>$PatenteV,'Activo'=>$Activo);
            }
            $stmt->close();
            if ($rows) {                        
                $data=array('data'=>json_decode(json_encode($rows)));
            } else {
                $data=array('error'=>'Registro no ingresado');
            }
        } else {
            $data=array('error'=>'Error en consulta SQL');
        }
        $conexion->close();
    } else {
        $data=array('error'=>'No hay conexión');
    }
} else {
    $data=array('error'=>'No se postearon datos');
}
} else {
$data=array('error'=>'Método no permitido');
{
header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

posteriormente lo llevo para android, en el cual estoy trabajando con fragment el cual se denomina repuestos, en esste cargo los datos, a través del inflater, primero recupero el campo de la patente y posteriormente llamo al llenarSpinner2(), de la siguiente manera:

```
private void llenarSpinner2() {
    try {
        String url = "http://192.168.1.90/gestion/buscar_presupuesto5.php";
        Log.d("WEB", "URL: " + url);
        cliente.get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                Log.d("WEB", "onSuccess: " + statusCode);
                if (statusCode == 200){
                    cargarSpinner2(new String(responseBody));
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                Log.d("WEB", "onFailure: " + statusCode + "\nError: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void cargarSpinner2(String respuesta) {
    ArrayList<Presupuesto2> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(respuesta);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("data");
        if (jsonArray != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject item = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Presupuesto2 c = new Presupuesto2();
                c.setID(item.getInt("ID"));
                c.setFilas(item.getString("N_Filas"));
                c.setCantidad(item.getInt("Cant_Repuestos"));
                c.setRepuesto(item.getString("Repuestos"));
                c.setValor(item.getInt("Valor_Repuestos"));
                c.setPatente(item.getString("Patente_Vehiculo"));
                lista.add(c);
            }
        } else {
            // No se encontraron datos en el JSON
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ArrayAdapter<Presupuesto2> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Presupuesto2>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, lista);
    spid.setAdapter(adapter);

        spid.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long idl) {
                Presupuesto2 c = lista.get(position);
                String url = "http://192.168.1.90/gestion/buscar_presupuesto5.php?Patente_Vehiculo=" + c.getPatente() + "&N_Filas=" + c.getFilas();
                cliente.get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                        Log.d("WEB", "onSuccess: " + statusCode);
                        if (statusCode == 200){
                            txtid1.setText(lista.get(position).getID()+ "");
                            txtitem3.setText(lista.get(position).getFilas());
                            txtcantidad.setText(lista.get(position).getCantidad()+ "");
                            txtrepuesto3.setText(lista.get(position).getRepuesto());
                            txtvalor2.setText(lista.get(position).getValor()+ "");
                            m.setText(lista.get(position).getPatente());
                            cmdingresar.setEnabled(false);
                            cmdmodificar.setEnabled(true);
                            txtcantidad.requestFocus();
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

                    }
                });
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
}
```

en el cual al realizarlo a través del debug me indica en la string respuesta ("Error no se postearon los datos") y por ende la lista en size=0, además les comento que en este fragment trabajo con dos spinner más y ninguno de estos presenta problemas e incluso el mismo código sino en este en particular, favor de ayudarme ya que llevo varios días en esto y no puedo encontrar el error, desde ya muchas gracias.